# Dirichlet problem for the half plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

In solving this problem, for a separated solution, set $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y).$ Then 
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=-\lambda,$$
yields two ODEs: (with $\lambda=\beta^2$ for $\beta >0$)
$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0 \implies X(x)=A \cos \beta x + B \sin \beta x,$$
$$Y''(y)-\lambda Y(y)=0 \implies Y(y)=C \cosh \beta y + D \sinh \beta y.$$
Combining these two and form the sum:
$$u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ( A_n \cos \beta_n x + B_n \sin \beta_n x ) \cdot ( C_n \cosh \beta_n y + D_n \sinh \beta_n y ).$$

Since the problem is defined for $y >0,$ we need $u(x,y) \rightarrow 0$ as $y \rightarrow -\infty.$ Still, I don't know how to continue here on ward and completing the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your approach is that the problem is not in a compact domain, so we should not expect there to be a discrete countable set of eigenvalues. Therefore the solution has to be an integral instead of a sum. It is also easier to use exponentials than trig. functions for this case.

Separating variables, you have the correct equations, but let's write the separation constant as $\lambda=k^2$, and then we have solutions
$$ X_k(x) = A(k) e^{ikx} + B(k) e^{-ikx}, \quad Y_k(y) = C(k) e^{ky} + D(k) e^{-ky}, $$
where the dependence on the eigenvalue has been made explicit. Now, to keep $u$ bounded as $y \to \infty$, we need to also take the $Y_k$ bounded as $y \to \infty$: i.e., $e^{-\lvert k \rvert y}$; we can discard the coefficient since it plays no further rôle that cannot be taken up by those in $X_k$.

The total solution is then
$$ u(x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx-\lvert k \rvert y} A(k) \, dk. $$
Of course, now we have to find $A(k)$ using the boundary conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$, or
$$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} A(k) \, dk. $$
This is a Fourier transform, so we proceed in the same way as Fourier series, by multiplying by $e^{-imx}$ and integrating with respect to $x$ (we assume that this integral makes sense, or this approach doesn't work; the final answer can still be obtained this way, but by a more complicated limiting process):
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-imx} f(x)\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-imx} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx} A(k) \, dk \, dx. $$
Changing the order of integration on the right,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-imx} f(x) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix(k-m)} \, dx \right) A(k) \, dk. $$
At this point we use the orthogonality relation for the Fourier transform, which is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ix(k-m)} \, dx = 2\pi \delta(k-m), $$
which may be shown in a number of different ways, such as using a cutoff to make the integral finite and taking the limit. Hence we find, using the property $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(k-m) A(k) \, dk = A(m) $,
$$ A(m) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-imx} f(x) \, dx, $$
and so we have
$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ikx-\lvert k \rvert y} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ikx'} f(x') \, dx' \right) dk. $$

In this case, we can simplify this further: change the order of integration again to get
$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x') \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ik(x-x')-\lvert k \rvert y} \, dk \right) dx'. $$
The inside integral is straightforward, and can be done by splitting it at zero: we find that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ik(x-x')-\lvert k \rvert y} \, dk = \frac{2y}{(x-x')^2+y^2}, $$
so the neatest answer is
$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y}{(x-x')^2+y^2} f(x')  dx'. $$

---

Another way to derive this involves calculating the Green's function for Laplace's equation on the upper half-space, and using Green's third identity to get this integral more directly; you haven't given enough context to determine which is the intended method.

Comment: That's a disastrous mistake I did. I wasn't aware of the fact that it's not a infinite sum but an integral. So I can only use the Fourier series approach when the domain is compact ? Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: I was a little imprecise: as @zaq points out, unbounded in *both* directions means that the eigenvalues are not discrete: essentially, discreteness comes from satisfying the boundary conditions. For Laplace's equation, separating variables gives eigenvalue equations, which need to be in Sturm–Liouville form to have discrete eigenvalues. There are other S–L equations (e.g. the Hermite equation) where the interval is infinite but the eigenvalues are discrete. [...]

Comment: [...] Another example using Laplace's equation is in 2D polar coordinates: separating variables gives $\Theta''(\theta)+m^2 \Theta(\theta)=0$, which has discrete eigenvalues because the interval is finite. On the other hand, in 3D the situation is more complicated: we can have one set of discrete, and one of continuous, as in $\nabla^2 u=0$ on $-\infty < x < \infty$, $y>0$, $0<z<1$. Then we have *two* separation constants, one of which takes discrete values, the other taking continuous ones. If you would like more detail, I suggest you ask another question.

Comment: At the moment I don't have any. I'll if I get one. Thank you.